# Java alternative to PHP Tokenizer

Tags: java, tokenize

Is there any Java alternative to PHP Tokenizer?

http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php

Edit: I mean Java class that parses Java like PHP Tokenizer parses PHP.

Comment: Meaning a Java class that parses PHP? Or a Java class that parses Java?

Comment: Java class that parses Java.

Comment: Your question could be improved by including a short description of the documentation you are linking to, and perhaps a little detail on what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

I quickly scanned the documentation you linked to. It looks like functionality for parsing PHP code.

If that is indeed what you are looking for, you might find the [JavaParser project](http://javaparser.org/) useful. It contains functionality for parsing Java source code.

[This page](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/wiki/Manual) contains some usage examples.

Comment: Look at one of the examples on the page.

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just to add some information to @Henrik answer: JavaParser project gives an API through a Visitor Pattern that allows to move through  the AST of a Java Class. In my opinion, the only feature missing (currently), is that the AST parsing leaves comments (non-javadoc) out, either they are single line or multiline. Voting up for valuable information.

Comment: @pabrantes: Great addition. I also miss the ability to parse any type of Java code, not just entire classes, e.g. a method or an expression.

Comment: @Henrik: In my case I always have a full class to parse, so it's not a real problem, but I do agree with you that being able to parse any java expression would be a great feature!